# How to do the uninstall process by using UI dialog box?

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, uninstallation

i.e. If i click the uninstall button in UI dialog box It should process uninstall for my msi file. what things i need to add to the wix coding and is that custom action need for this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a custom action.
You will have to include one of the Wix provided dialog sets as part of your installer source code.

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/dialog_reference/wixui_minimal.html

Your requirement can very well be met by making use of the WixUI_Minimal dialog set.

For an example of how to include a built in dialog set to your installer, please see the following URL:

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_dialog_library.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: I looked all the inbuild dialog sets on that link..But I can't find my particular dialog set for uninstall please help me @Kiran Hegde

Comment: please anyone guide me for this purpose I didn't get the solution for this so long time. Thank you in advance